# AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get', Python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

Мне нужно поочередно выдернуть `text` и `text2` из блоков `example` из HTML кода ниже.

```
<div class = "example">
    <div class = "text">
        <p>Пример</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "text2">
        <p>123</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "example">
    <div class = "text">
        <p>Пример 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "text2">
        <p>456</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я пробовал вот такой код:

```
blocks = soup.findAll("div", "example")
for block in range(len(blocks)):
    for i in blocks[block]:
        print(i.get("div", "text"))
        print(i.get("div", "text2"))
```

Но он выдает ошибку `'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get'`.
Я также пробовал писать `i.find()` вместо `i.get()`, но это не помогло.
Других идей по реализации этого у меня нет, что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю проблема в Вашей конструкции, попробуйте так:

```
    blocks = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'example'})
            for block in blocks:
                print(block.find('div', attrs={'class': 'text'}))
                print(block.find('div', attrs={'class': 'text2'}))
```